# R: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have my data as the `class DataFrame` from the library `VariantAnnotation`, and I run into problems when I try to add a new row.

Example:

```
> score <- c(1L, 3L, NA)
> df <- DataFrame(score)
> df
DataFrame with 3 rows and 1 column
      score
  <integer>
1         1
2         3
3        NA
> df[["variant"]] <- c("a", "c", 2)
> df
DataFrame with 3 rows and 2 columns
      score     variant
  <integer> <character>
1         1           a
2         3           c
3        NA           2
```

When I try to do the same to my data:

```
> dim(genotypes)
[1] 768775     27
> length(rownames(genotypes))
[1] 768775
> genotypes[["variant"]] <- rownames(genotypes) 
Error in genotypes[["variant"]] <- rownames(genotypes) : 
more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

If I do the equivalent using a data.frame, I do not got any errors

```
> genotypes<-as.data.frame(geno(get(assignment))$GT)
> dim(genotypes)
[1] 768775     27
> length(rownames(genotypes))
[1] 768775
> genotypes$variants <- rownames(genotypes)
```

I really need to use a `DataFrame` for this analysis, as they are very heavy for the memory, and `DataFrame` is more memory efficient than `data.frame`.

Hope there is a smart head in here that can help me :-)

Cheers

Comment: Could it be because you wrote "variant" the first time and "variants" the second ?

Comment: That name could be anything...

Comment: So "variants" and "variant" are the same object ?

Comment: "variants" and "variant" is just a name I give the new column that I add to the object "genotypes". It could be anything.